# Why can't I create a trigger with PDO?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am trying to automate my trigger process so that I don't have to manually create triggers for every table I want to use. Unfortunately, I get an error back saying there is a syntax error.

Here is my code

```
$updateTrigger = "DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS {$table}Update
    CREATE TRIGGER {$table}Update AFTER UPDATE ON $table
    FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
       DECLARE N DATETIME;
       SET N = now();
       INSERT INTO StagesHistory (Stage, StageID, Date, Action)
       VALUES ('$table', NEW.ID, N, ?);
    END";

$ut = $dbh->prepare($updateTrigger);
$ut->execute(array($update));
$error = $ut->errorInfo();
```

Evaluating `$error` returns this error message:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CREATE TRIGGER TranslationUpdate AFTER UPDATE ON Translation
>           FOR EACH R' at line 2

I can't figure out what error it's talking about. What's the problem, and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`DROP TRIGGER ...` and `CREATE TRIGGER ...` are two separate statements. You need to at least separate them with a `;`, possibly execute them in separate queries.

Comment: Wow, that was incredibly simple

Answer (score 1):

Isn't a semicolon missing? It should be like: `DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS {$table}Update;`.